# Validate user input

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, dsl, xtext

I've implemented the following rules in my Xtext DSL:

```
House:
    'House' name=ID
    description=STRING?
    ('height' height=DOUBLE heightUnit=UNIT)? &
    ('width' width=DOUBLE widthUnit=UNIT)? &
    'end' 'House' 
    ;

enum UNIT:
        m = 'm' |
        cm = 'cm'
    ;
```

It allows me to define the following, using the editor based on that DSL:

```
House MyHouse
    "This is my house"
    height 15.5 m
    width 3000.2 cm
end MyHouse
```

How can I validate the units, defined by the user? For example, both height and width should have the unit *m* and if the user defines something different (*cm* for example), the editor should show an error.

I've checked [this](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.xtext.doc%2Fcontents%2F030-tutorial-next-steps.html) site, which describes how to create validation rules, but where do I have to register them, so that they can work perperly?

**UPDATE:** As described in Ravens comment under his post, I've used reverse engineering and added the correspondig package and class, which now looks like the following:

```
package com.language.validation

import com.language.mylanguage.House
import org.eclipse.xtext.validation.Check

class MylanguageValidator {

    @Check
    def unitCheck(House house) {
        val hWidth = house.width

        if (hWidth != null) {
            if (!hWidth.equals("m")) {
                val errorMsg = "House width must be defined in m";
                // error method undefined
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The Package of the class is inside the plug-in project `com.language.mylanguage`. I am trying to validate, if the user used *m* as the unit. If not, an error message should appear. The method `error()` is undefined. Do I have to import or extend another class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your language's mwe2 workflow is probably missing the ValidatorFragment. This fragment creates the stub and does the guice bindings for you so you only have to fill the class with logic.

Comment: True! After adding it to the mwe2 workflow the class is generated automatically and I can add my validations to it. Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In your project folder you have a few packages and one of them is named yourDSLName.validation.
In this package there is a xtend class where all validation rules have to be specified. 
So in there you add your test-method in the form

```
@Check
def unitCheck(House house) {
   val hUnit = house.getHeigthUnit()
   val wUnit = house.getWidthUnit()

   if(hUnit != null && wUnit != null && !hUnit.equals(wUnit)) {
       val errorMsg = "Units have to be the same!"
       error(errorMsg, #Package.eINSTANCE.House_widthUnit)
   }
}
```

Note: You have to replace the #Package with the packageName of your DSL.

**UPDATE:**
You have to extend the class "AbstractMyLanguageValidator"
  
  
Greetings Raven

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick response! If the package is not there (the project was not created by me), can I add it additionaly? How would the class look like?

Comment: Do you know the language name? If so you can reverse engineer the name... For example the package for the language with the name "myLanguage" is in the Package "myLanguagePackage"

Comment: Do I have to implement the Abstract class or should it be created automatically? Because such a class can't be found.

Comment: If it is not. Can I use reverse engineering again, to create it somehow? :) Do I have to register it somewhere?

Comment: I don't know...Sorry but I haven't dealt with that kind of situation before either. But You have the grammar and I assume you have installed the Xtext Framework so when you just use this grammar and generate a new Xtext project out of it everything you need should be there... :)